# How Can We Prove Flatness from an Induced Exact Sequence?

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, projective-module, flatness, injective-module

I want to prove that for every short exact sequence
$$
O \to A \xrightarrow{f} B \xrightarrow{g} C \to O 
$$
of $R$-module homomorphisms, if the induced sequence
$$
O \to M\otimes_R A \xrightarrow{\operatorname{id}_M\otimes f} M\otimes_R B \xrightarrow{\operatorname{id}_M\otimes g} M\otimes_R C \to O 
$$
is exact, then $M$ is flat over $R$.

I know that $M$ is flat if given a short exact sequence, the induced sequence is exact. However, the question I am asking here goes in the reverse direction, and I don't know how to go about it. I will appreciate your help.

Thanks.

Comment: To me, that's the *definition* of being flat, and definitions are always "if and only if."

Comment: @Randall I thought as much. However, I found that one author uses the “iff” like you mentioned and calls it a proposition, not a definition. Another author gave three equivalent statements and says the case that we can deduce flatness from the question I posted is easy. He didn’t say it follows from the definition of flatness. Hence my concern.

Comment: What is your definition of flat?